# An equality for the dimension of the sum of subspaces (in the non-degenerate case)

Tags: linear-algebra

This post is a sequel of [An inequality for the dimension of the sum of subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375583/an-inequality-for-the-dimension-of-the-sum-of-subspaces), inspired by [this famous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23501/34538) on $\dim(U+V+W)$.

The inequality $$\dim(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} U_i) \le \sum_{r=1}^{n} (-1)^{r+1} \sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_r} \dim(\bigcap_{s=1}^{r}U_{i_s}) $$

is an equality for $n \le 2$, is true for $n = 3$ (but not an equality in general, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23501/34538)), and false for $n \ge 4$ (see the answers of Quid and Darij Grinberg in the first link).

The set of intersections of the form  $\bigcap_{s=1}^{r}U_{i_s}$ with $0 \le r \le n$ and  $i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_r$ is a finite poset.
The system is called **non-degenerate** if the $2^n$ intersections above are $2$-$2$ distinct, which implies that the poset above is a boolean (algebra) lattice $B_n$; for example $B_3$ is :
[image]
The counter-examples for the equality at $n=3$ and for the inequality at $n=4$, are both degenerate.

**Question**: Is the equality (or at least the inequality) true in the non-degenerate case?

Comment: Take my counterexample $\left(U_1, U_2, U_3, U_4\right)$, and take a non-degenerate quadruple $\left(V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4\right)$ for which equality holds (e.g., pick a $4$-dimensional vector space with basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$, and let $V_i$ be the span of $e_1,e_2,\ldots,\widehat{e_i},\ldots,e_4$). Now $\left(U_1\oplus V_1,U_2\oplus V_2,U_3\oplus V_3,U_4\oplus V_4\right)$ (in the direct sum of the ambient spaces of the two quadruples) should be a non-degenerate counterexample.

Comment: What does "2-2 distinct" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: this means 2 by 2 non-equal.

Comment: Thanks. So, what does it mean for a bunch of things to be "2 by 2 non-equal"? Is it different from just saying the things are distinct?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: yes "2 by 2" is useless here.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: you're right! What if we add the assumption "irreducible" (i.e. not the direct sum of two systems)?

Comment: Hmm. I fear this is becoming more and more a question about indecomposable representations of the four-subspaces quiver...

Comment: @darijgrinberg: why do you "fear", is it an open problem?

Comment: It isn't (e.g., https://daim.idi.ntnu.no/masteroppgave?id=4316 ), but the characterization is beyond my understanding.

Comment: The OP has requested migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still false.

Take my counterexample $\left(U_1,U_2,U_3,U_4\right)$ from [An inequality for the dimension of the sum of subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375583/an-inequality-for-the-dimension-of-the-sum-of-subspaces) , and take a non-degenerate quadruple $\left(V_1,V_2,V_3,V_4\right)$ for which equality holds (e.g., pick a $4$-dimensional vector space with basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$, and let $V_i$ be the span of $e_1,e_2,\ldots,\widehat{e_i},\ldots,e_4$). Now $\left(U_1\oplus V_1,U_2\oplus V_2,U_3\oplus V_3,U_4\oplus V_4\right)$ (in the direct sum of the ambient spaces of the two quadruples) should be a non-degenerate counterexample.

Comment: Nice thank you! I've open a new post on MO for a non-degenerate indecomposable system, in the more general case of a finite factor, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/212488/34538). In the [von Neumann algebra theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra), a matrix algebra $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is a finite factor of type ${\rm I}_n$, but there also exists finite factors of type ${\rm II}_1$, for which the problem makes sense.